# Calculation statistical inaccuracy

Tags: probability

How do I calculate/express mathematically the statistical accuracy/inaccuracy of the specific results of a specific number of "dice" rolls?

Lets say I get a crate with *some contents* a number of times. I know what contents CAN be in the crate, but I do not know the probability of getting all type of content, only the probability of the most rare (type 4 from the list below) is known within some range (for example we know the probability lies within 1/5000-1/1000). How many times would I have to open a crate to be sure that the results would be reliable to represent a "close enough" probability of the actual precise probability?

Content type probability:

1. ? but somewhere > 1/1000
2. ? but more rare than 1 and somewhere > 1/1000
3. ? but more rare than 1 and 2 and > 1/1000
4. ? but somewhere between 1/5000-1/1000

How many crates do I need to open to be *relatively* certain that the results represents the actual probability of each content type? Lets say relative certaincy is when the probability is >= 99% accurate.

My guess would be that opening 5000 crates would not be enough, I am guessing I would have to open at least 100(or 99 times?) times as much as the least probable occurence of getting content of type 4, to be sure I have less than 1% risk of not getting a content of type 4. (So I am simply guessing here I would have to open 100*5.000 = 500.000 crates to have only 1% risk of not getting a type 4 crate or is this wrong?)

How can I express all this mathematically?

Comment: What you want is the normal distribution. This wikipedia page has the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know what the term was called in mathematics. Thanks

Comment: You can now post an answer to your own question

Comment: Ok I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the normal distribution. This wikipedia page has the answer. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution – Ethan Bolker

Comment: Well you can accept this answer, so the question will no longer appear on the active list. What I'd expected to see here was the actual numerical calculation you ended up with.

Comment: yeah I had to wait some time for some reason, so didn't get to do that before after the "select answer" countdown was finished yesterday. I will update it then when I finally understand the whole thing and have time to do it and update the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "a very large sample" depending on precisely what you mean by *relative certainty*.

Suppose for example, as a simplification, you wanted to be able to distinguish between the probability of type 4 being either $\frac1{5000}=0.0002$ or $0.000202$ - a $1\%$ difference - initially thinking each to be equally possible, and you wanted a $99\%$ probability of making the correct choice.

You might for example take a sample size of about $1.1\times 10^9$ and choose the lower probability when a proportion $0.000201$ or fewer of them are type $4$ and choose the higher probability when you observe a higher proportion.   That sample size is about $\Phi^{-1}(0.99)\times \frac{0.0002(1-0.0002)}{(0.000201-0.0002)^2}$ coming from using a normal approximation to the binomial and its inverse CDF

Comment: Thank you for the help!